# Embed variables aren't correctly parsed in the low search result parameters

Tags: low-search, embeds, parameters

Embed variables aren't correctly parsed in the low search result parameters

I have this code for my low search results.

```
{exp:low_search:results
{if embed:author_id}author_id="{embed:author_id}"{/if}
...
{if embed:query}query="{embed:query}"{/if}
}
...
```

Seems simple enough. However, when I outputted the `$data` values in my
`low_search_pre_search` hook, I get this

```
array(
['embed:author_id}author_id'] =>
...
['embed:query}query'] =>
)
```

Why did it parse the parameters that way?

Answer (score 4):

[As I told you earlier today](https://getsatisfaction.com/low/topics/embed_variables_arent_correctly_parsed_in_the_low_search_result_parameters), this is **not a Low Search issue**, but a conditionals parsing issue. If you turn on Template Debugging, you'll see the opening tag just before it is actually executed. It will look something like this:

```
{exp:low_search:results {if embed:author_id}author_id=""{/if} ... }
```

*That* is what's executed, and what EE uses to set the internal `ee()->TMPL->tagparams` array, which in turn is used by Low Search.

But if you change the tag to a native Channel Entries tag, *you will see the same effect*; ie. the unparsed conditional.

Turns out that **if an embed variable isn't set**, that conditional is treated as an **advanced** conditional, and therefore parsed **after** the tags, making them unsuitable to use to set/hide parameters like that.